# Should I put the Test classes in the UML?

Tags: testing, uml, software-design

Should I put the test classes in the UML diagram? I can't find any "best practice" about this!

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Firstly "the UML diagram" suggests that you are creating a single diagram. This is definitely not good practice. Create as many diagrams as needed lighting certain aspects of the model. So - test cases would be one of those aspects. That means: put them in (a) separate diagram(s).

Answer (score 1):

To add a suggestion, if you want to model tests, you can look to UML testing profile ( [UTP link](http://utp.omg.org/)) it provides needed elements to model tests, requirements and so on.

You can use SysML also since it integrates a part of UTP.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely depends on context.  Who is going to use the UML model and what will they use it for?  In general I would say that adding test classes is going to clutter a UML model and make it difficult to understand - so no.  But if the context is that the testing is what you want to explain, then clearly the test classes are going to be pretty important.

As Thomas Kilian points out, creating a number of diagrams from one underlying model is probably the right answer - and being able to do this is one of the reasons you would use UML rather than a simple diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This is a preference. You can choose to or choose not to.

I would say it's *better* practice to have the tests modeled into the solution. But I wouldn't claim I always follow best practices

There are many diagrams needed in modeling a solution. I would focus on three: Analysis, Design, and Implementation. All three are class diagrams. All three define your solution at different abstractions.

In the analysis, you're closest to the requirements and the beginning of your solution. In here, you would want to have broad classes. I would not put tests in here since this diagram is still trying to get the shape of the solution from the user and their requirements. An analysis diagram would only have class names in a box, with lines which show their associations.

The design diagram would go into a little more detail on how classes would be built. The blueprint of the application would take shape in the design. This design can be given to any programmer and they write code which would build the solution. The interesting part of the design diagram is that it could also be given to a test engineer and they would write proper tests for the solution to be created.

The implementation diagram is the lowest level class diagram which is created. Most times, I would create this in retrospect. The implementation diagram should be a verbatim translation of the codebase. In the implementation diagram, I would have my test classes included for completeness.

Note, these are my views which I sometimes do not follow to the letter because of business constraints. However, in an ideal world, this is how I would prefer my modeling done.